# how to avoid checkbox bring to front

Tags: vb6

I want to hide the checkbox when there is a new form pop out, below highlighted is the issue encounter.

[image: schedule details form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to right-click the checkbox on the form itself in the designer and select send-to-back.  If that's not it, then you have another checkbox inside your "pop-up" frame control that either needs to be deleted or have its visible property set to false.  You might only think it's the checkbox underneath the frame because by coincidence it occupies the same location.  I'm betting it's actually contained in the frame overlay itself.

Comment: working fine with right click > send to back. Thank you for the solution ya @Bill Hileman